# How much buffering does table-driven lexing require?

Tags: rust, lex, lexical-analysis, dfa

I am writing a POSIX shell implementation in Rust. This comes with some rather awkward requirements:

- Input must be read line by line. If input is from a non-seekable source, that means that input must be read one byte at a time.
- Backslash-newline, when unquoted, is line continuation. It is _not_ a token separator, and ideally should be taken care of prior to lexing.

Both of these requirements can be easily dealt with if the lexer reads one character at a time and allows rules to set internal state that can be queried by the lexer's source of characters (Rust does not allow the C solution of stuffing the state in global variables). My current lexer does just that. However, it is 398 lines of highly repetitive code, including some (inadequate) tests. This code begs to be auto-generated.

Auto-generated lexers usually use a table-driven design based on finite automata. I am not very familiar with this, and am wondering if lookahead is inherent in this design or is usually not used. If no lookahead is usually used, then I can probably modify an existing lexer generator to do what I want; otherwise, I am probably stuck with hand-written code.

Answer (score 2):

This has the potential to be a question that is too broad or generates answers containing too much opinion, which is not a [good attribute of an SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Its very much a portmanteau of a question, asking about the implementation of existing lexer generator algorithms, the programming of finite automata, the lexical requirements of a shell language and the characteristics of Rust programs and probably a few more topics besides.

First, lets deal with the question about the capabilities of tool generated lexers. Let's consider one of the most commonly available, `flex` the GNU lexer generator. The answer is **yes**; it can build you a lexer that does what you want. It is sufficiently flexible and contains enough different features to do the jobs (as do other similar tools). Will it be easy and straightforward? Not necessarily. The tool enables you to use the built in reading and finite state automata, but you can provide your own input routines, write your own state machine, or even handle the difficult bits within pieces of self-written code (in **C** or C++). There are plenty of examples of how to achieve this in the manual, tutorial web sites, tutorial videos, text books and [questions here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flex-lexer?sort=active).

How does that help you when coding in Rust, as flex generates code in **C** or C++? We need a Rust based lexer. Once can do a literature search and see what is available. Wikipedia is good for lists, and has a [list of available parser and lexer generator tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis#List_of_lexer_generators). However,  none of these generate Rust. There are such tools in Rust, however:

- [RustLex: lexical analysers generator for Rust](https://github.com/LeoTestard/RustLex/)
- [RACC - Rust Another Compiler-Compiler](http://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/2qewc0/racc_rust_another_compilercompiler/)

As both of these are experimental works-in-progress you'll need to evaluate them for yourself.

Another alternative is to make your own version of an open source tool (like `flex`) to work with Rust. This could be done in two ways:

1. You could post-process the output of `flex` to convert the **C** code to Rust code and then compile it.
2. You could amend the code for the tool to generate Rust instead of **C**. (It does not need to be written in Rust itself for you to achieve what you desire.)

These approaches has been done several times to enable the targeting of other new languages. There are, as a result, [a whole raft of compiler generator tools for a myriad of languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_parser_generators).

The next question is the size and nature of your hand written lexer code. [There are standardised and recognised ways of programming finite state automata in any language. Experienced programmers would should know the pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automata-based_programming):

```
while ( NOT <<EOF>> ) {
  switch ( next_symbol() ) {

     case state_symbol[1]: 
              ....
             break;

      case state_symbol[2]:
              ....
              break;

       default:
             error(diagnostic);
  }
}
```

Which can even be done functionally as:

```
action[state_symbol[next_symbol()]];
```

It is possible to hand-write quite a compact and efficient regular language parsing FSA to do the lexing, but it is a matter of experience in the language and the algorithms.

Your wide and imprecise question has resulted in a wide and imprecise answer: Yes, everything is possible, and **No** it is not dependent on buffering and backtracking.